# Open file that is in the resource folder/inside jar

Tags: java, maven

I have standard maven project structure:

```
-src
 |
 --main
   | 
   ---java
   ---resources
      |
      ----file.txt
```

I need to read this file on app start (read DB schema and execute SQL script, so this file is opened via `FileReader`). When app is built, then using the following code gets it from `project/target/classes/file.txt`:

```
getClass().getResource("/file.txt").getFile()
```

This file also appears in the root of the result jar file. And after app start it cannot be accessed because it is searched near the jar file not inside.

How to access this file when it is inside jar/resource folder?

Comment: What happened when you used the classloader instead of the class? What happened when you removed that slash?

Comment: When I remove slash - NPE occurs. If I use ClassLoader and remove slash, the file is searched in `target/classes/`.

Comment: Are you sure your resources directory is being included in the jar? If so, where?

Comment: @KevinWorkman, If I unpack result jar file, my `file.txt` is in the root of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to read the file as a resource, not as a file with

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
```

Relevant question and answers can be found here:

[How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1464291/1987208)

Comment: Yes, I've tried this already and `getResourceAsStream` is the best way, I think, to do it.